# Syntax to create a double[,] in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, double

This seems extremely simple, yet I can't seem to find applicable documentation anywhere. In C#, how do you create a 'double[,]'? Specifically, the data I'm trying to represent is something like this:

```
[0,0] = 0
[0,1] = 1
[1,0] = 1
[1,1] = 2
```

I have tried [[0,1],[1,2]] and the equivalent with {{}{}} and {[][]} and various other things, but cannot seem to figure out the syntax. It seems that a simple [0,1] alone is a 'double[,]' but I would like to find a way to represent the above data (more than just 2 numbers).

What am I missing? If anyone can point me to some simple documentation, that would be great.

Comment: `double[,] d = {{0,1},{1,2}};` but keep in mind that `double[,]` != `double[][]`. If you chose the latter, it would have to be `double[][] d = {new double[] {0,1}, new double[] {1,2}};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Array initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx):

> For a multi-dimensional array, the array initializer must have as many levels of nesting as there are dimensions in the array. The outermost nesting level corresponds to the leftmost dimension and the innermost nesting level corresponds to the rightmost dimension. The length of each dimension of the array is determined by the number of elements at the corresponding nesting level in the array initializer. For each nested array initializer, the number of elements must be the same as the other array initializers at the same level.

In our case:

```
double[,] a = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 } };
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had tried that but apparently missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-dimensional double array:

```
        Double[,] newdouble = new Double[2,2];
```

or

```
        Double[,] newdouble = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a two dimensional array that you can assign to, you are going to need to first allocate the correct size. In this case, you have 2 rows and 2 columns, so that will be a [2,2].

```
double[,] twod = new double[2,2];
```

Next you simply assign to it like this

```
twod[0,0] = 0;
twod[0,1] = 1;
twod[1,0] = 1;
twod[1,1] = 2;
```

And then work with it however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There is three ways to initialized your array:

```
double[,] twoDemn = { { 0 , 1 }, { 1 , 2 } };
```

or:

```
double[,] twoDemn = new double[,] { { 0 , 1 }, { 1 , 2 } };
```

or:

```
double[,] twoDemn = new double[2,2];
twoDemn[0,0] = 0;
twoDemn[0,1] = 1;
twoDemn[1,0] = 1;
twoDemn[1,1] = 2;
```